# Project referring to an older version of the dll file - System.buffers.dll version 4.0.2.0

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I'm wondering what the issue could be.
When i run the application it shows the error below in the error log file.

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

The version of the system.buffer.dll file that the project references is 4.0.3.0 but when the application is run it looks for version 4.0.2.0 and i'm wondering how i can fix that error.

**Solution i have tried so far**

i have opened the .csproj  and the app.config files to check which version is referenced and it's version 4.0.3.0.

```
<Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>References\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Open nuget package manager and first downgrade the System.Buffers dll to 4.0.2 then upgrade to 4.0.3 again and build

Comment: check the binding redirects in app.config or web.confi

Comment: Hello, that version is not available for download

Comment: @Artur i added the binding redirect to the app.config file and the error is gone. Thanks.